Why does my script create a new trigger every time?
I am slowly teaching myself how to use Google Apps Script. I wrote a script that sorts Google Form results in reverse chronological order (so that the most recent submission is always at top). I successfully got it to run the script and sort on every form submission, but it creates a new trigger every time, so that after 25 form submits the triggers have piled up and I get a "exception: this script has too many triggers" error message.
Here is what I have written, if someone can give me some advice about what I am doing wrong, I appreciate it:
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getActiveSheet()
  var lr= s.getLastRow()
  var lc=s.getLastColumn()
  var data=s.getRange(1,1,lr,lc)
  data.sort( { column : 1, ascending: false } )

}

I also tried writing into the script to delete the trigger afterwards, using:
 var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
 for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) 
   ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);

so it successfully deletes the triggers but it also stops sorting the submissions too.

The script creates a trigger on every execution because it has the following statement on the top level / global scope
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

To avoid having this problem, put the above statement inside a function block.
function createTrigger(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}

Whenever you want to create a trigger you might run this function from the Google Apps Script editor by clicking Run or Debug.
